# How to connect to your Rasperry Pi via SSH

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, cmder

I have just bought myself a Raspberry Pi 3 B+, and now I'm trying to connect to it from my normal laptop via SSH. I've already activated SSH in the raspian config.

I use the program `cmder` for the whole thing.

The problem is that every time I try to connect to my rasperry pi with

```
ssh {username}@{hostname} (ssh pi@rasperrypi)
```

the following error occurs: `ssh: Could not resolve hostname rasperrypi`

Both devices are connected by LAN with the same router.

Do you guys have an idea what may have caused this error?

Comment: try replace rasperrypi with ip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the IP, instead of the hostname, now to find the [IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address) you could either go to your router web interface and check for the DHCP leases or from your workstation try  this:

```
$ arp -an
```

Hopefully, that will list the IP your Raspberry PI is using so that you could use it:

```
ssh user@X.X.X.X
```

Where `X.X.X.X` is the IP.

Depending on the size of your network you may need to scan for all hosts with port 22 open this can be done using nmap:

```
$ nmap -sn -n -PA22 192.168.1.1/24
```

In this case, it will scan network `192.168.1.1`, to find your network in Linux you could use:

```
$ ip route | grep default
```

In macOs:

```
$ route get 0.0.0.0 | grep gateway
```

or:

```
$ netstat -nr | grep default
```

Then try again [arp](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=arp&sektion=8), example of output:

```
$ arp -an
? (169.254.55.233) at a1:cf:c8:c0:a8:a5 on en0 [ethernet]
? (192.168.1.1) at 50:4c:a3:6a:a2:8 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (192.168.1.3) at 50:4c:a3:57:55:52 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (192.168.1.4) at 50:4c:a3:57:5d:44 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
```

Find the [mac address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) from your device and use the IP to ssh into it.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is related with name resolution. Check if you have the "rasperrypi" hostname and related IP added in your /etc/hosts.